# OS X app crashes while loading root nib file

Tags: macos, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I have strange situation where app is crashing during review process where running fine on all  system. I have tested it on mac book/air/ mac mini and all are on lion. App works totally fine but after submitting to app store; tester is saying it is crashing; below are the crash logs:

```
    Process:         My app [73375]
Path:            /Applications/My app.app/Contents/MacOS/My app
Identifier:      com.mycompany.myapp
Version:         1.5.2 (539)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [11718]

Date/Time:       2012-02-15 15:00:15.459 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50)
Report Version:  9
Sleep/Wake UUID: A9CEF38F-05E5-48BD-8BA4-076E419F99E6

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000091fc8358

VM Regions Near 0x91fc8358:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001092d9000-00000001092fd000 [  144K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/My app.app/Contents/MacOS/My app

Application Specific Information:
objc[73375]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff91fa5c6d _hasObjcContents + 178
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bd71021 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 49
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bd70fa2 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 274
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cc61b2f -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1245
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cc5809f loadNib + 322
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cc5759c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cc574b7 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cc573fa +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ceca9b3 NSApplicationMain + 398
9   com.mycompany.myapp     0x00000001092da274 0x1092d9000 + 4724

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ddac192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c112594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c113b85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ddac7e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8a9565be _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8a95514e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ddac192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c112594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c113b85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00000001093a5050  rcx: 0x0000000000000001  rdx: 0x00007fff68ed84ac
  rdi: 0x00000001093a5d20  rsi: 0x00000001092f0a14  rbp: 0x00007fff68ed87d0  rsp: 0x0000000091fc8358
   r8: 0x0000000000000021   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007fd9f483c850  r11: 0x00007fd9f4839c90
  r12: 0x00007fff91fa5be0  r13: 0x0000000400475e00  r14: 0x00000004004a17c0  r15: 0x015d000000000001
  rip: 0x00007fff91fa5c6d  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000091fc8358
Logical CPU: 2
```

Well i have observed same behavior while i try to run app for profiling. Please help me.

Regards,
M P.

Comment: Please help....Seems like app is crashing 10.7.3..Any help will be appritiated.

Comment: You say you observe the same behavior when running the app for profiling. What happens if you migrate some of the objects in your root XIB out to other XIB files?  Or re-order the objects in your XIB file?  Also look for accidental disconnections or orphaned outlets.

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. I will surly look into it. Basically it is a single window Tab based application so it only has one XIB. I got it from other developer so if i refactor it then it will take time. How can i check for accidental disconnection or orphaned outlets?

Comment: Step through each object in your XIB and look for yellow X's in each object's potential connections, which would indicate a broken outlet or action.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try today and will let you know.

Comment: @Michael, i tried and has removed a few unused links but i am still facing same issue. It is not happening always; it just happens sometime and most of the time on 10.7.3. As i told you that i was also getting an crash while running in profiler but after removing those unused outlet links it is no more crashing but people still facing this issue? Any other way to get it done.